# JSF 2.0 redirect error

Tags: jsf-2

I get an `IllegalStateException` when redirecting from a `preRenderView` event. I have worked around it by just ingoring the exception. Is there a cleaner way to achieve the same result?

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class LogoutBean implements Serializable
{
    public void preRenderView(ComponentSystemEvent e)
    {
        userSessionBean.logout();
        FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        try
        {
            ctx.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(ctx, null, "/pages/index?faces-redirect=true");
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException exc)
        {
            // Ignore. This exception is caused by redirecting after the response is already committed. The redirect works anyway.
        }
    }

    @Inject
    private UserSessionBean userSessionBean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to send a redirect by [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29) instead.

```
public void preRenderView(ComponentSystemEvent e) throws IOException {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("pages/index.xhtml");
}
```

Comment: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();` had no effect. I'm a bit uncomfortable with the 2nd option because I lose the view ID abstraction.

Comment: Hmm, oh of course it would have no effect. You're inside the render response phase already! I edited the answer to remove the suggestion.

Comment: Another problem is that I'm using UrlRewriteFilter and it seems the explicit redirect bypasses the URL encoder which UrlRewriteFilter relies on.