# What is the difference between redirect and navigation/forward and when to use what?

Tags: redirect, jsf-2, navigation, forward

What is difference between a navigation in JSF

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(context, null, url);
```

and a redirect

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
response.sendRedirect(url);
```

and how to decide when to use what?

The issue with navigation is that page URL does not change unless `faces-redirect=true` is added to the query string of the navigation URL. However, in my case appending `faces-redirect=true` throws error if I want to redirect to a non-JSF page like a plain HTML page.

And another option is as BalusC suggested at [JSF 2.0 redirect error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526251/jsf-2-0-redirect-error)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

First of all, the term "redirect" is in web development world the action of sending the client an empty HTTP response with just a `Location` header with therein the new URL on which the client has to send a brand new GET request. So basically:

- Client sends a HTTP request to `somepage.xhtml`.
- Server sends a HTTP response back with `Location: newpage.xhtml` header
- Client sends a HTTP request to `newpage.xhtml` (this get reflected in browser address bar!)
- Server sends a HTTP response back with content of `newpage.xhtml`.

You can track it with the webbrowser's builtin/addon developer toolset. Press F12 in Chrome/IE9/Firebug and check the "Network" section to see it.

The JSF navigationhandler doesn't send a redirect. Instead, it uses the content of the target page as HTTP response.

- Client sends a HTTP request to `somepage.xhtml`.
- Server sends a HTTP response back with content of `newpage.xhtml`.

However as the original HTTP request was to `somepage.xhtml`, the URL in browser address bar remains unchanged. If you are familiar with the [basic Servlet API](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info), then you should understand that this has the same effect as [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29).

---

As to whether pulling the `HttpServletResponse` from under the JSF hoods and calling `sendRedirect()` on it is the proper usage; no, that isn't the proper usage. Your server logs will get cluttered with `IllegalStateException`s because this way you aren't telling JSF that you've already taken over the control of the response handling and thus JSF shouldn't do its default response handling job. You should in fact be executing [`FacesContext#responseComplete()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#responseComplete%28%29) afterwards.

Also, everytime whenever you need to import something from `javax.servlet.*` package in a JSF artifact like a managed bean, you should absolutely stop writing code and think twice if you're really doing things the right way and ask yourself if there isn't already a "standard JSF way" for whatever you're trying to achieve and/or if the task really belongs in a JSF managed bean (there are namely some cases wherein a simple [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) would have been a better place).

The proper way of performing a redirect in JSF is using `faces-redirect=true` query string in the action outcome:

```
public String submit() {
    // ...
    return "/newpage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Or using [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29) when you're not inside an action method such as an ajax or prerender listener method:

```
public void listener() throws IOException {
    // ...
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/newpage.xhtml");
}
```

*(yes, you do not need to put a `try-catch` around it on `IOException`, just let the exception go through `throws`, the servletcontainer will handle it)*

Or using [`NavigationHandler#handleNavigation()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/NavigationHandler.html#handleNavigation%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) in specific cases if you're using XML navigation cases and/or a custom navigation handler with some builtin listener:

```
public void listener() {
    // ...
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    NavigationHandler nh = fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
    nh.handleNavigation(fc, null, "/newpage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
}
```

As to why the navigation handler fails for "plain HTML" files, that is simply because the navigation handler can process JSF views only, not other files. You should be using `ExternalContext#redirect()` then.

#### See also:

- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-make-url-reflect-the-current-page-and-not-the-previous-one/15523045#15523045)
- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink/4317723#4317723)

Comment: Thanks Balu for elaborate explanation. I am new to JSF and this helps me understand the nuances. Also referred your comment on the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458911/reset-jsf-backing-beanview-or-session-scope - adding an empty string does return me to the starting page but also displays error message as invalid handler found. I cannot use faces-redirect=true here since i want to return some message back to the start page. Any pointers?

Comment: If the redirect is on the same path, then you could use `Flash#setKeepMessages()` to keep all `FacesMessage`s in the flash scope.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, you have just saved me from suicide by Ajax. I have been fighting un-responsive buttons for months on two different projects. The new pages, when launched by JSF, were having all of their events pre-consumed unless a random selection of command buttons  had ajax="false" liberally scattered about. Having re-read your reply to this post, it occurred to me to try the re-direct to clear the form workspace inside JSF. It worked an absolute treat both in page and from backing bean actions. The downside is that I now have to re-visit all of my code.

Comment: I think there is a typo here:

"Client sends a HTTP request to somepage.xhtml.
Server sends a HTTP response back with content of newpage.xhtml. "
You sent request to "Somepage.xhtml" but got the content of "newpage.xhtml", 
So, am i right? or there is something i am missing =?

Comment: @Muntaser: nope, no typo. The statement *"You sent request to "somepage.xhtml" but got the content of "newpage.xhtml""* is correct. If you're still not understanding it, take a step back and learn basic Servlets first before diving deeper into JSF.