# Redirect to a servlet by implicit navigation?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, servlets

How can I propertly redirect to a servlet by a backing method?

```
class MyBean{ 
    public String doRedirect() {
        //some conditions
        return "newlocation";
    }
}


<h:commandButton value="Test" action="#{myBean.doRedirect}" />
```

This would redirect my to a newlocation.xhtml.

But what if I have a WebServlet?

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/newlocation")
```

How can I then redirect to the servlet instead to an xhtml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use JSF navigation handler to navigate to a non-JSF resource.

Just use the [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29) method directly:

```
public void doRedirect() throws IOException {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("newlocation");
}
```

Or if you're unsure about the current request path:

```
public void doRedirect() throws IOException {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/newlocation");
}
```

Comment: Ok cool, thanks for this hint! Is it better to use `.redirect` or `.dispatch`?

Comment: The `dispatch()` does a forward, not redirect. You explicitly asked "redirect" which is an entirely different process. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277366/jsf-redirect-options

Answer (score -1):

You can access the raw HTTPServletResponse and do a redirect using its API

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
response.sendRedirect(URL);
```