# Previous Page URL JSF

Tags: java, jsf

I'm working with a JSF application and I'm seeing the URL that appears in the browser's navigation bar is always for the page I just left, rather than the page I'm on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because you are forwarded(not redirected) to another page from server, To redirect you need to set the following param with your return

```
?faces-redirect=true
```

Comment: you mean that if method returns for example page called "home"...then it should return "home?faces-redirect=true" or what you mean...i will be thankful if you explain with example

Answer (score 4):

That will happen if you're using POST for navigation by e.g. commandlinks/commandbuttons. If it's pure page-to-page navigation and you actually don't need to submit anything to the server, then you've a bigger problem. You will indeed get exactly this nasty "side effect" and your links will not be bookmarkable nor searchbot-crawlable. PRG ([Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)), as suggested by other answers, will indeed solve the bookmarkability ("one URL behind") problem, but it surely won't solve the inability of searchbots to crawl/index the pages.

Just don't use POST for plain page-to-page navigation in first place. Use GET for that. Use `<h:link>` instead of `<h:commandLink>` and so on. In code, replace all

```html
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="Next page" action="nextpage" />
</h:form>
```

by

```html
<h:link value="Next page" outcome="nextpage" />
```

#### See also:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)
- [What is the difference between redirect and navigation/forward and when to use what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277366/jsf-redirect-options/11277482#11277482)

Answer (score 0):

By default, JSF performs POST operations directed to the original page's URL. If you use a `<navigation-rule>`, you can specify `<redirect/>` to let the browser perform an additional request, so the target page's URL will appear in the navigation bar.

Comment: what if i am not using <navigation-rule>, i mean that link action go to Method in the Server and this Method returns Target Page Name as String.

Comment: If you return a String (!= null) from an action method, it will be used as an input to all existing navigation rules. If there are no navigation rules, the return value will be ignored.