# Managed bean Constructor is not getting fired in page navigation

Tags: jsf, jspx

I am using MyFaces 1.1.14. I have two JSPX pages with JSF components and my managed bean is in request scope. At first page, bean constructor is getting fired and when I submit a form it is fired again. But after my app navigates to the new page, it is not getting fired. The constructor is supposed to be called, right?

The thing is that page is accessing some properties of the bean — those setters get called — no problem with that, but why is the constructor not called? When the page get loaded I need to get data from previous process (i.e from different framework). What is the problem with my understandings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation does by default not fire a new HTTP request. Instead, a different view is been used as content of the current HTTP response. Only when you navigate with a redirect by appending the `<redirect/>` entry to the `<navigation-case>`, then a new HTTP request would be created.

You should totally understand it if you're familiar with [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) concept of [the basic Servlet API](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) which JSF is sitting on top of.

#### See also:

- [What is the difference between redirect and navigation/forward and when to use what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277366/what-is-the-difference-between-redirect-and-navigation-forward-and-when-to-use-w/11277482#11277482) - Note that the code examples are targeted at JSF 2.x, but the principles apply as good on JSF 1.x.

Comment: Thank you.Yes, it doesnt fire a new request(I can able to see it using debugBar tool). I'll try by appending the `<redirect>`.