# Why does the page change in JSF, but not the URL?

Tags: jsf, url, jsf-2, navigation

I have simple test web-application: 
First Page - index.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<html>
 <h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
 </h:head>
 <h:body>
    First page
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="Go to Next page" action="next"/>
    </h:form>
 </h:body>
</html>
```

and Next Page - next.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<html>
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
 </h:head>
 <h:body>
    Next page
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="Go to First page" action="index"/>
    </h:form>
 </h:body>
</html>
```

When I run my application i have that url on browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/Test/
```

and index.xhtml as first page.

Then when I click "Go to Next page" i have url

```
http://localhost:8080/Test/index.xhtml
```

and next.xhtml page. And when I click "Go to First page" page changes (to index.xhtml) but url its

```
http://localhost:8080/Test/next.xhtml
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
 <context-param>
     <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
     <param-value>Development</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <listener>
     <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <session-config>
     <session-timeout>
         30
     </session-timeout>
 </session-config>
 <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

What should I do to make that the first page in my application has a URL,

```
http://localhost:8080/Test/index.xhtml
```

rather than

```
http://localhost:8080/Test/
```

?

I use  Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.37

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using command buttons (POST form submit buttons) for plain page-to-page navigation. This is completely wrong. You should be using plain buttons (GET navigation buttons) for this instead.

Replace the

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Go to Next page" action="next"/>
</h:form>
```

by

```
<h:button value="Go to Next page" outcome="next" />
```

Note: you don't need a `<h:form>` at all.

Your concrete problem of "one URL behind" is caused because you're seeing the URL of `<h:form>` itself being reflected in browser address bar instead of the URL of the form submit's result page. Open the JSF page in your webbrowser, rightclick and *View Source* and look closer at `<form action>` value.

#### See also:

- [Difference between h:button and h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070537/difference-between-hbutton-and-hcommandbutton)
- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink/)
- [What is the difference between redirect and navigation/forward and when to use what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277366/what-is-the-difference-between-redirect-and-navigation-forward-and-when-to-use-w)
- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-make-url-reflect-the-current-page-and-not-the-previous-one/)

Comment: Ok, but when I use <h:button />  security-constraint didn't work ?

Comment: This problem is caused somewhere else. Perhaps you're misinterpreting the problem? Security constraints won't be applied on pages forwarded by `<h:commandButton>`. Perhaps you forgot to actually replace `<h:commandButton>` by `<h:button>`? Press "Ask Question" button if you still stucks. This is completely unrelated to the current question.

Comment: ok, its my mistake with not invalidate session. Last question: when i use `<h:button>` i can't make any action in managed bean ? I have to use `<h:form>` and `<h:commandButton>`?

Answer (score 12):

Though it's an old thread, if someone is still looking for it can try "?faces-redirect=true". Like:

```
<h:commandButton value="Go to Next page" action="next?faces-redirect=true"/>
```