# primefaces- graphic image not direct an url

Tags: jsf, url, primefaces, graphicimage

I use primefaces 3.1, in menubar i want to add icon .When user click the icon,it will be direct to the home.jsf page.Below,when user click the icon,page goes to index but its url seems different.Thanks for any helps.

```
<p:menuitem >
  <p:commandLink action="home.jsf" >
     <p:graphicImage height="24" 
                     width="24" 
                     value="resources/images/home.ico" 
                     style="border:none" />     
  <p:commandLink>
</p:menuitem>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon submitting of `<h:form>` by any command components like `<h/p:commandButton>`, or `<h/p:commandLink>` JSF performs a forward and not a redirect. That is why your URL stays the same. Just append `?faces-redirect=true` to your `action` attribute and it'll work as expected. For the distinction visit BalusC's answers to [What is the difference between redirect and navigation/forward and when to use what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277366/what-is-the-difference-between-redirect-and-navigation-forward-and-when-to-use-w) and [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-make-url-reflect-the-current-page-and-not-the-previous-one).

That said, it's a poor practice to perform navigation by using command components. Use `<h:link>` or `<h/p:button>` components instead. They trigger a get request to the navigation case outcome, thus, your URL will change. Command components are designed to trigger server actions and not performing plain navigation. For more information consult BalusC's answer to [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink).