# how is the bean accessed first time?

Tags: jsf, el, facelets, managed-bean

I am going through the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/webapp003.htm) of Java EE 7 in oracle.

Here is a simple form that gets User name in a input box:

```
<h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:graphicImage url="#{resource['images:duke.waving.gif']}"
                            alt="Duke waving his hand"/>
            <h2>Hello, my name is Duke. What's yours?</h2>
            <h:inputText id="username"
                         title="My name is: "
                         value="#{hello.name}"
                         required="true"
                         requiredMessage="Error: A name is required."
                         maxlength="25" />
            <p></p>
            <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" action="response">
            </h:commandButton>
            <h:commandButton id="reset" value="Reset" type="reset">
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
```

I see that `value="#{hello.name}"` is used in the code. what does this line do?

This is what is mentioned in the [tutorial link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/webapp003.htm):

*The web page connects to the Hello managed bean through the Expression Language (EL) value expression #{hello.name}, which retrieves the value of the name property from the managed bean.*

**Q1)**  But the first time the form is loaded, there is no name attribute attached to hello bean. so Fetching that should return null correct?

**Q2)** Secondly, how does the value entered in the input box bind to the hello bean's name attribute?

In fact, after the form is submitted, the page is redirected to "response.xhtml" where the value of hello bean's name attribute is fetched in the same way i.e  `#{hello.name}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer:

- Q1: correct
- Q2:

  1. On each page rendering elements, bound to `#{hello.name}` will receive the value, returned by `Hello.getName()` method.
  2. On each form submit (in case form is valid), `Hello.setName(param)` will be called with *`param`* equals to `value` of element, bound to `#{hello.name}`

## Longer answer:

You have:

1. `Hello.java`, the class annotated with [`@Named`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Named.html) and [`@RequestScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/RequestScoped.html)
2. `<h:inputText value="#{hello.name}" />` inside `<h:form>` on `index.xhtml`
3. `#{hello.name}` inside `<h2>` on `response.xhtml`

---

Prerequisites:

- `@Named` is a [CDI annotation](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/cdi-intro.html).
- When application is deployed, the server "registers" `Hello.java` as a managed bean.
- `@Named` could be used as `@Named(name="explicitHelloName")`, but if argument isn't provided, the bean will be registered as "lower cased class name", so, after your application is deployed, we have **hello** to be used wherever it needed.
- `@RequestScoped` says that data of each `Hello` instance will "live" only during request-response (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7031941/991954) for scoping details).
- [This article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) greatly describes JSF lifecycle. We are interested in two fazes of it:
  `RENDER_RESPONSE` and `UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES`.

---

Let's go step by step:

## I. Browser requests `index.xhtml`

FacesServlet's responsibility (because we are mapping all `*.xhtml` files to `Faces Servlet` inside `web.xml`) is to build html and return it as a response.

Building consists of several phases (look [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#TheFirstCall) for details), one of which, RENDER-RESPONSE:

1. Builds a `UIViewRoot`
2. Recursively builds `UIViewRoot`'s children.

During **2)** for children, that has some EL expressions, these expressions being "resolved".

In your case we have `#{hello.name}` expression, bound to `value` of an `UIInput` (`h:inputText` is an `UIInput`).

`<h:inputText>` will be rendered as HTML's `<input type="text">`.

FacesServlet "understands" that value for this input should be taken from something that `#{hello.name}` represents.
To get the value:

1. FacesServlet "asking" for **hello** from container (server)
2. Container searches for registered **hello**, finding `Hello.java`, instantiating it and gives to FacesServlet.
3. FacesServlet calling for **`getName()`** ([JavaBean convention](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/SCJP/0120__Object-Oriented/JavaBeansNamingConvention.htm) to get the "name") of `Hello` instance  and receives the value of `Hello`'s private field **`name`**, which after class instantiation is `null`.
4. FacesServlet writes `<input>` without `value` to response and on index.xhtml you see an empty input.

---

## II. When you press submit button

...and form is valid, there is `UPDATE_MODEL` phase (more detailed [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#TheFormSubmit)),.

For our `h:inputText` component FacesServlet again searches for **hello**, finding an instance of `Hello` and calls **`setName(value)`** on it.
As `<h:commandButtons>`'s `action` attribute is `response`, browser is about to receive *response.xhtml*'s content (this is not a redirection, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11277482/991954), so, `@RequestScoped` **hello** isn't being recreated).

---

## III. response.xhtml

...has `<h3>Hello, #{hello.name}</h3>`, so, again, FacesServlet must resolve it as described earlier.

But in current request the `Hello`have been instantiated and it's field `name` was already set (in `UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES` phase) with the value you entered to `input`, so, `<h3>Hello, YOUR_SUBMITTED_TO_INPUT_TEXT_VALUE</h3>` is written to response and displayed in browser.

---

More details about expressions can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html)

## Edit

If you use `<h:comandButton action="response?faces-redirect=true"/>` on the `index.xhtml`, then after **II** there will be a redirect to response.xhtml, and `Hello` bean become recreated, so, you will see "Hello, " (`name` will be `null`)

Comment: From II to III, browser redirect is same request or a different request. because when `#{hello.name}` is set in first request and after redirection, that bean could be null because it is `@requestscoped`

Comment: From II to III there are no redirect, but forwarding; i have edited the answer.

Comment: @brainstorm having a `RequestScoped` bean does work with form submissions, because the actual binding happens AFTER the Submission you perform, meaning the value is correctly set for the CURRENT Request - Where you can read the value you just submitted. Just if you store a value which you are not including in your form-submission it will be "lost" when the page reloads.

Comment: @dognose: that is correct. it is set for CURRENT request. but once the action (in my case redirection) is performed, it is a NEW request and the value set may not be retrieved.. If it is Forwarded, then it is same request and it holds the data..