# POST redirect from managed bean

Tags: jsf

I have a simple JSF and managed bean and I need to make POST redirect when page render and some condition is true. JSF:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{myBean.error=null}">
    <p>Some data</p>
</h:panelGroup>
```

In managed bean, the `init()` method, annotated as `@PostConstruct` and in this method I do

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    if (someCondition) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        String redirectUrl = "http://myurl.com";
        ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

        try {
            ec.redirect(redirectUrl);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(e.getMessage());
            context.addMessage(null, message);
        }
    }
}
```

but I need navigate user to redirectUrl with POST params and cannot find how to do it.
With button it will be like this:

```
<form method='post' action="myUrl">
    <input type='hidden' name='param1' value='value1'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='param2' value='value2'/>
    <input name='button'  type='submit' value="Button">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you try to achieve is not possible that way.

A redirect will send a http 302 status code to the client with a location header including an url where to redirect to. Then the client will make a get request to that url and your post data will be lost.

There are alternatives to achieve this, here are some ideas.

- You could forward the request using the [ExternalContext.html#dispatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#dispatch%28java.lang.String%29) method, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277366/what-is-the-difference-between-redirect-and-navigation-forward-and-when-to-use-w) for the differences. Note that this does not change the url in the browser's address bar.
- You could store the post data in the user's session.

Comment: Option 3: use a filter and let JSF out of this.