# Why I must do two clicks

Tags: jsf, primefaces, hyperlink

I have a template with the Logout Link of name "Cerrar Sesión"

```
<div id="top">
    <ui:insert name="top">
        <h:form>
            <h:commandLink value="Cerrar Sesión" action="#{loginBean.cerrarSesion}" />
        </h:form>
    </ui:insert>
</div>
```

My Bean has the `cerrarSesion` function:

```
public void cerrarSesion() throws IOException {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.invalidateSession();
    ec.redirect("../view/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
}
```

The Project URL is: http://192.168.1.72:8083/PROJECT/

My problem is if I click on "Cerrar Sesión", the URL changes to http://192.168.1.72:8083/PROJECT/faces/view/inicio.xhtml, the same page where I was (it refreshes).

When I clicked on "Cerrar Sesión" again, the program redirects correctly:
http://192.168.1.72:8083/PROJECT/faces/view/index.xhtml

I am using JSF with PrimeFaces, NetBeans, and GlassFish.

Comment: I was noticing    ec.invalidateSession(); maybe it's possible it doesn't redirect, and breaks.  Try removing that line and seeing if anything changes.

Comment: Could you also try like the first example by BalusC here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277366/what-is-the-difference-between-redirect-and-navigation-forward-and-when-to-use-w. If still nothing works, do you have nested forms?

Comment: You didn't post the problem in MCVE format, so it's merely guessing to the cause. Perhaps it's this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408130 If not, please post a MCVE.

Comment: Hmm, my jsf wouldn't show the link or anything in the body of a ui:insert. It only would insert the contents of a previous ui:define with name="top".

An action must be a method, that returns a String. The value will be the outcome, null means the same page.