# How to navigate from master to details view on rowSelect event in JSF

Tags: ajax, jsf, navigation

BalusC shows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459903/creating-master-detail-pages-for-entities-how-to-link-them-and-which-bean-scope) that in order to do the navigation we can use

```
    <h:column>
        <h:link value="Edit" outcome="/products/edit">
            <f:param name="id" value="#{product.id}" />
        </h:link>
    </h:column>
```

which is fine, but how to do the same if I don't want an additional column as a navigation - I want to do it onclicking the row.

What I've tried. The list.xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable id="datalist" ....>
     <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{listController.onRowSelect}" />
```

Which goes to bean:

```
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) throws IOException {
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("edit.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&id=" + listItem.getId());
}
```

and this in fact navigates me to new page after clicking a row in a datatable, the url is:

```
http://localhost/app/faces/edit.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&id=1686
```

so id of a row on datatable is appended.
What happens is of course the NULL:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /edit.xhtml @18,84 value="#{listController.item.id}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
```

The edit.xhtml:

```
   <ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="body">            
        <h:form id="itemForm">               
            <f:metadata>
                <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{listController.item.id}" />
            </f:metadata>
```

Obviously I am doing sth wrong.

Comment: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("edit.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&id=" + listItem.getId());
}` is 'duplicate' . The `faces-redirect=true` is superfluous. And the error means most likely that listcontroller is not found (resolved)

Comment: Or `ListController.getItem()` returns `null`?

Answer (score 0):

The `onRowSelect()` method is an AJAX call (assuming you're using PrimeFaces). In this case, it's difficult to use the standard JSF way for sending redirects, as follows:

```
public String submit() {
    return "/teams_detail.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Instead, you can use `ExternalContext` and call `redirect()` on it, as follows:

```
ExternalContext ecoxExternalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
ecoxExternalContext.redirect(ecoxExternalContext.getRequestContextPath() + "/teams-flow/team_detail.xhtml");
```

---

Read more on this on BalusC's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11277482/3987745

Answer (score -1):

```
    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) throws IOException {
     setItem(listItem); //you need to set the item before you try to access
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("edit.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&id=" + listItem.getId());
}
```